# How do I remove CSS from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've used the Sanitize Ruby gem with the following code:

```
result = Sanitize.clean(html)
```

It pulls the content from the page, but I still have this CSS in the sanitized result. How do I get rid of it so I just have the page text?

```
#fsb-social-bar { width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb; border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb; padding: 10px 0; margin: 0px 0 20px 0; float: left; background: #fff; position: relative; clear: both; } #fsb-social-bar a { border: 0px !important } #fsb-social-bar.fsb-fixed { position: fixed; top: -2px; z-index: 99999; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-title { display: block; float: left; margin: 3px 20px 0 0; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-facebook { width: 120px; float: left; padding: 3px 0 2px; height: 25px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-facebook.fsb-hide-count { width: 44px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 30px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-twitter { float: left; width: 135px; padding: 3px 0 2px; height: 25px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-twitter.fsb-hide-count { width: 61px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 30px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-google { float: left; width: 105px; padding: 3px 0 2px; height: 25px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-google.fsb-hide-count { width: 33px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 30px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-linkedin { float: left; width: 135px; padding: 3px 0 2px; height: 25px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-linkedin.fsb-hide-count { width: 61px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 30px; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-pinterest { float: left; width: 115px; padding: 3px 0 2px; height: 25px;} #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-pinterest.fsb-hide-count { width: 43px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 30px; } #fsb-social-bar .socialite { display: block; position: relative; background: url(http://www.example.net/wp-content/plugins/floating-social-bar/images/fsb-sprite.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; } #fsb-social-bar .socialite-loaded { background: none !important; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-service-title { display: none; } #fsb-social-bar a { color: #333; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-twitter { width: 105px; height: 25px; background-position: -13px -10px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-twitter .fsb-count { width: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0 0 69px; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-google { width: 75px; height: 25px; background-position: -136px -10px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-google .fsb-count { width: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0 0 41px; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-google .socialite-button { margin: 0 !important; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-google .socialite-loaded .socialite-button{padding: 2px 0 0} #fsb-social-bar .fsb-facebook { width: 89px; height: 25px; background-position: -231px -10px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-facebook .fsb-count { width: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0 0 52px; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-facebook .socialite-button { margin: 0 !important;} #fsb-social-bar .fsb-share-facebook .socialite-loaded .socialite-button {padding: 2px 0 0} #fsb-social-bar .fsb-linkedin { width: 105px; height: 25px; background-position: -347px -10px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-linkedin .fsb-count { width: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0 0 70px; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-linkedin .socialite-button { margin: 0 !important; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-pinterest { width: 88px; height: 25px; background-position: -484px -10px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-pinterest .fsb-count { width: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0 0 50px; color: #333; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-pinterest .socialite-button { margin: 0 !important; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-clear { clear: both; } #fsb-social-bar .fsb-clear:after { clear:both; content:; display:block; height:0; line-height:0; overflow:auto; visibility:hidden; zoom:1; } @media (max-width: 768px) { #fsb-social-bar.fsb-fixed { position: relative !important; top: auto !important; } } Facebook2 Twitter1 Google+0 LinkedIn0 Pinterest0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras at nisl auctor, dignissim odio vel, suscipit velit. Vivamus pretium velit quis sapien scelerisque ullamcorper. Vivamus ullamcorper lacus non magna suscipit laoreet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla aliquam dolor nec neque auctor pretium. Nullam vitae enim nisl. In imperdiet lacinia nunc at congue. Aliquam posuere nulla vel ornare accumsan. Fusce vitae sapien et nulla fringilla congue quis eu tellus. Nunc vestibulum turpis eget convallis cursus. Integer ut sapien molestie odio interdum luctus. Vestibulum urna justo, sagittis ut sodales eu, rutrum a magna. Proin consequat convallis nibh vel semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque eu purus quis massa lobortis eleifend.
```

The solution needs to work on not only this text, but any string that could happen to have CSS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your CSS code is inside a style tag, you can use this one:

```
Sanitize.clean(content, :remove_contents => ['script', 'style'])
```

Other solution is [css_transformer.rb](https://gist.github.com/avinasha/1113327.).